# How to use Canvas.SetTop in custom ink canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, canvas, attached-properties

This is in followup of my previous problem. The situation is that I have a custom ink canvas that inherits from InkCanvas.

When using Canvas.SetTop(control, Y), or CanvasSetLeft(control, X) followed by

CustomInkCanvas.Children.Add(control)

The control defaults to the the origin (0,0), not the (x,y) position.

Is this due to the attached properties from the InkCanvas not being available in my CustomInkCanvas?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try setting the `(x,y)` after adding it to children list.

Comment: @Rohit  I tried...no good. I keep thinking I need to inherit the attached properties, but do not know how to do that.

Comment: I have added an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

*All attached properties are automatically inherited*. You need not to inherit it manually.

Moreover, InkCanvas has exposed its own Left, Top, Right and Bottom properties. So, you need to call it's methods instead of Canvas.

Instead of

```
Canvas.SetTop(control, Y)
```

you need to call

```
InkCanvas.SetTop(control, Y)
```

to set the attached property. Similarly for Left property you need to call InkCanvas method.